# Programmatic way of resource loading in WPF

Tags: wpf, resources

It is very easy to load an image in XAML:

`<Image Source="Resources/Images/pic.png" />`

I wonder is there a simple way to do it programmatically?
I've found the following solution (spent half a day):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + 
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName +
  ";component/Resources/Images/pic.png", UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
Image im = new Image();
im.Source = img;
Grid.SetColumn(im, 1);
grid.Children.Add(im);
```

As to me, it looks ugly and very COM-like. 
It has no flavor of .NET FCL (carefully and thoroughly thought over) class library. Why should we use strings like: "pack:...", anyway? Enumerations are much better (a kind of Resources.Local).

I hope there is more elegant way to do the job. Thank you.

Comment: @AngelWPF: XAML is good for people with twisted brains, but the code you suggested throws exception with InnerException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Path to image is right, because it works with an ugly looking syntax of "pack://application:,,,/. . . etc".

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you assign a value "img" to the "Name" property and try this from the code in a line?
    
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Koala.jpg"));

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way is XAML itself. :-)

.... As for code behind it can be elegant too ...

```
        var img
            = new Image()
                  {
                      Source =
                          (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFrom(
                            "Resources/Images/pic.png") as
                                ImageSource
                  };
```

Comment: Dear AngelWPF. XAML is OK but the code throws exception with InnerException: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}